# I don't know how to write a command to show direction to my file in macOS console, JAVA

Tags: java, macos, console, sublimetext3

I'm learning Java, and usually run via console, write code in Sublime text editor. I'm macOS user. So, I create a file.java in my desktop, then in console write something like this:

1. cd desktop
2. javac (nameOfMyClass).java
3. java (nameOfMyClass)

But you know it's sometimes not useful, for instance i've a file in a folder, not in the desktop. I don't know the command to show the direction to the folder. Cd...

Could you help me ???

Comment: Is your problem finding the file from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

u go check the path manually, then go write on your terminal(i guess that's what you called console ...) and write cd (the path of your script) then run it as you usually do it should be .
Check out what's javap for

Answer (score 0):

Using the terminal is definitely a good skill to know. There are lots of commands and it can be overwhelming!  Unix systems (Like Mac) handle paths in two ways: absolute and relative paths. To access the file using the absolute path, you could type in

`java /Users/<YOUR-USERNAME>/Desktop/folder/someOtherFolder/file.java`

The nice thing about that is that you can access your file that way from anywhere on your computer even if you cd into another folder. Note that the beginning of the path starts with "/".  In your example you are actually accessing the file using a relative path.  You already used "cd" to "Change directory" into your Desktop, so think of it already being in that folder. When you call `java file.java` to run it, it is exactly the same as the full command above, but because you're in your Desktop folder already, you are accessing the file using the path "Relative" to where you currently are. To find out where your terminal currently is you can use the command `pwd` for "Present Working Directory" if you ever forget.  If there is a folder in Desktop, you can simply access the file by providing the rest of the path from where you "are".  The terminal adds the rest of your "Present Working Directory" to the beginning. Note that the path does NOT have the "/" at the start

`cd /Users/<NAME>/Desktop` (now your terminal is "in" the Desktop "folder", using the absolute path)

`pwd`

`java folder/someOtherFolder/file.java` (Using the relative path from your desktop)

If you want to see what's IN the folder so you know how to navigate, just type in `ls` and it will display all the subfolders and files contained.  Similarly, you can `ls` a folder using absolute and remote paths.

`ls`

`ls folder/someOtherFolder`

Quick tips: Type the beginning of the folder or file name and press TAB on your keyboard to complete the next folder in the path.  Pressing the TAB key twice will show the contents of the folder just like `ls` does.  If you want to navigate up one folder you can use `cd ..` to move the terminal out of the folder.

There is TONS to learn about the terminal but you'll really only use a couple of commands to get around, there are lots of resources online about it. Hopefully this answers your question!

EDIT: Of course if you wanted to access a file in a different folder, then you can just use the path of that folder, rather than the Desktop.

`cd /Users/<NAME>/Documents/projects`